# Can Multiple Parameter be used with LIKE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting data from database in a format like "chem*,bio*" what i want to do is after i split the string into two i want to fetch all records containing "chem" and "bio" .. using LIKE with multiple parameter is something i want since CONTAIN will bring in irrelevant data too. Kindly help.

its something like this

assume:
               @cwork2 ='chem*,bio*'

```
           @cw1=@cw1 +'OR contains (name,'''+@Cwork1+''')'

           @cw1=@cw1 +'OR name LIKE ('''+@Cwork1+''','%')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You can use **pipeline (|)** to achieve **Or Condition**

```
select * from Tablename where name like '[chem|bio]%';
```

Answer (score 0):

just add them in an OR condition.

```
@cw1 = @cw1 OR name like '%chem%' OR name like '%bio%'
```

Answer (score -1):

i found another way... although he answers provided are right on track but when talking about variables we cannot simply add on variables in the code. Hence forth i decided to put the variable in a @temp table, loop it through and then accordingly fetch data

```
   insert into @publication select item from fsplit(@Work,',') 
    Declare @loopc int=1
    while  (@loopc <= (SELECT count(*) from @pub))
Begin               
            set @Cwork1= (select name from @pub where id= @loopc);
    if CHARINDEX(@Cwork1,'*')<0
        Begin
                set @cw1='or pub.name ='''+@Cwork1+''')'
        end

    else

        begin
                set  @Cwork1 = REPLACE(@Cwork1,'*','%');
            set  @cw1=@cw1 +'OR pub.name LIKE ('''+@Cwork1+''')'

        end
        set @loopc= @loopc +1;
end
        set @cw1= (SELECT STUFF(@cw1, CHARINDEX('or', @cw1), LEN('or'), ''))
        set @cw1= '('+@cw1+')'
```

set @Au2= @Au2 + ' and '+ @cw1